# Ошибка установки приложения с помощью Android Studio.

Tags: android, android-studio

Здравствуйте, с чем может быть связанна данная ошибка ? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: прошу)если мой ответ верный)а он верный то прими его как правильный)и поставь пальчик вверх)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никакой ошибки  нет.Это предупреждение в котором говорится :
"У вас уже есть это приложение вы хотите удалить и записать его.При удалении данные не сохранятся"
У тебя же установлено это пиложенеи это окно говтри что я его перезапишу :) Вот так вот:))

Comment: 19:36 Session 'app': Error Installing APKs

Comment: Ну ошибка не изза этого.Поставте лог ошибок